# ul size is not around all child elements

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make a tabbed navigation element, which looks like this in html:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="selected">Selected Tab</li>
    <li><a href="#">Not-selected Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Not-selected Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see a stripped-down version of what I've made [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yDzpx/).

My question is: why is the `ul` not big enough to fit all the `li` elements? It seems to not be influenced by any border or padding added to the `li` elements.

Comment: I may be asking a stupid question, but after looking at the url, may I ask  what you mean by "why is the ul not big enough to fit all the li elements"?

Comment: Are you asking for something more like this? http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/aa431e022f8d9e4bd11f7af5c878627d/

Comment: @Forgetful I'm not sure how to phrase it otherwise. The bottom of the ul is not equal to the bottom of the li's and I would like it to be?

Comment: @Josh Yes, exactly like that. Why does that work though? Can you add it as an answer with a little more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
.nav li {
    display: inline;
    top: 9px;
}
```

use

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmnKj/)

Don't use `inline` if they are blocks, because then they don't generate a box block that pushes `<ul>`'s bottom.

And don't use `top: 9px`, because that moves `<li>` downwards, outside `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you're putting padding on the `li`'s while they're still inline elements. Additionally you're using `top: 8px` which is further complicating the problem. There are a few options to fix. 1: You make the `li`'s `display: inline-block` and remove `top: 8px`, OR  2. You float the `li`'s (and use a clearfix on the `ul`). Hope that makes sense.

[option 1 demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/aa431e022f8d9e4bd11f7af5c878627d)

[option 2 demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/ba901089912b2e338d6a2adfac16e8c7/)